# A couple of weekends a month

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is a sentence meaning question:

> Steve jobs is here **a couple of weekends a month**.

What does this sentence mean? Is this every weekends, accumulated weekends monthly? Etc... (p.s: in case if you would like to ask, this is an excerpt from Nat. Geo. I only changed the subject coz he is the person I look up to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A weekend is Saturday and Sunday especially when regarded as a time for leisure and in most countries no one works during these two days. I'm sure you know that fact. I'm also pretty sure that you know that in a month there are usually four weekends. Then, *a couple of weekends a month*, strictly speaking, would mean two weekends out of the entire month. So, what the sentence is saying is that Steve Jobs pays them a visit (he goes there and stays there for a while) every two weekends each month. It can be the first and the second weekends of the month or it can be the second and the fourth weekends of the month etc. The order is not important here, but the fact of the matter is that two random weekends out of one month are spent by Steve Jobs there. The following would be an equivalent statement to your original sentence:

> Steve Jobs goes there **two times a month**.

Are things starting to make sense to you now?

Comment: Yep, this is 4 days a month, at least, am I right?

Comment: @JohnArvin Yes, it literally does have that meaning, although the speaker might be speaking approximately.

Comment: @JohnArvin As snailplane said, technically speaking yes. Since a weekend is two days, then two weekends must be equal to four days. And therefore two weekends a month would be the same thing as four days a month.